# opencv face detection loop parameters

Tags: c++, opencv

I need explanation of the following loop for face detection in opencv

```
VideoCapture capture("DSC_0772.avi"); //-1, 0, 1 device id

Mat cap_img,gray_img;
vector<Rect> faces, eyes;
while(1)
{
    capture >> cap_img;
    waitKey(10);
    cvtColor(cap_img, gray_img, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::equalizeHist(gray_img,gray_img);
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_img, faces, 1.1, 5, CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE | CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, cvSize(0,0), cvSize(300,300));
    for(int i=0; i < faces.size();i++)
    {
        Point pt1(faces[i].x+faces[i].width, faces[i].y+faces[i].height);
        Point pt2(faces[i].x,faces[i].y);

        rectangle(cap_img, pt1, pt2, cvScalar(0,255,0), 2, 8, 0);
    }
```

I don't understand faces[i].x and the other for loop  parameters

how they are selected for face detection

Thanks for help

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Comment: what is  faces[i].x ,  faces[i].width and the other

Comment: How are we supposed to know?  How is `faces` declared in your code?  Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I have posted the full code

Comment: *"I have posted the full code"* - That's the problem. Create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

`faces` is a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of [`Rect`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#rect).  So the for loop is going through each `Rect` in the `vecto`r and it is creating two points.  `Rect` stores not only an x and y(of the top left corner) but also the height and width of the rectangle.  So `faces[i].x+faces[i].width` is taking the x coordinate of the rectangle plus its width and `faces[i].y+faces[i].height` is taking the y coordinate of the rectangle plus its height.  This is getting the opposite corner of the rectangle.  You are then feeding those points plus the image into the `rectangle()` function.

Comment: thanks for the explanation                                                                        the x coordinate of the rectangle is not very clear do you mean the starting x point for the whole rectangle